# Selected value in dropdown vue component

Tags: php, laravel, vue-component

I have a Vue component for form and there is a dropdown in that form as follows,

```
<select class="block appearance-none w-full"v-model="this.languages" name="language_id">
<option v-for="language in languages"  v-bind:value="(lan.id === language.id) ? lan.id : language.id" :selected= "lan.name"> {{ language.name }}
</option>
</select>
```

It is using the same vue component for both create & edit. In edit, there should be editing item's value (declared it as **lan**) as selected option in dropdown. I have tried as above & it don't have selected value. what is the wrong with my method?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately I found the answer. it is as follows,

```
<select class="block appearance-none w-full" v-model="lan.id" name="language_id">
<option v-for="language in languages"  v-bind:value="(lan.id === language.id) ? lan.id : language.id"
</option>
</select>
```

I have placed item's value in v-model.